# Combine es6 function every and sum and return boolean

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON response

```
{
    "nextAction": [{
            "userList": [{
                "id": 8,
                "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
                "name": "John Doe"
            }],
            "buttonLabel": "Finalize Now"
        },
        {
            "userList": [{
                "id": 10,
                "email": "newemail@gmail.com",
                "name": "Test User"
            }],
            "buttonLabel": "Start Now"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `userList` array sometimes contain `null` object. 
I am working on a condition which satisfies the below 3 conditions.

1. The `nextAction` array should be non-empty.
2. The `userList` array shouldn't contain the `null` element.
3. The `currentUser` should be present in the `userList` array.

```js
const data = [{
  "userList": [{
    "id": 8,
    "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "John Doe"
  }],
  "buttonLabel": "Finalize Now"
},
{
  "userList": [{
    "id": 10,
    "email": "newemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Test User"
  }],
  "buttonLabel": "Start Now"
}]

function checkForMyNextActions(myNextActions, currentUser) {
  const checkUsername = obj => obj.email === currentUser;
  return (myNextActions.forEach((myAction, index) => {
    (myAction.userList.length &&
      myAction.userList.every(userList =>
        userList !== null) &&
      myAction.userList.some(checkUsername)
    )
  }))
}

var result = checkForMyNextActions(data, "testemail@gmail.com")
console.log(result)
```

The expected result is true whereas I get undefined.

Comment: as side explanation of your result : `forEach` will not return anything, i.e. will return `undefined`. And when you do `undefined && anything`, you will always get `undefined`as  a result in JavaScript. For solutions, see existing answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this via [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) & [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var obj = {
  "nextAction": [{
    "userList": [{
      "id": 8,
      "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
      "name": "John Doe"
    }],
    "buttonLabel": "Finalize Now"
  }]
}

const getUser = (usr) => obj.nextAction.some(({
    userList
  }) =>
  userList ? (userList.every(userList => userList !== null) &&
    userList.find(y => y.email === usr)) : false)

console.log(getUser("testemail@gmail.com")) // true
console.log(getUser("test@gmail.com")) // false
```

The nice thing about `some` method is that it returns boolean if one element matches the condition which in our case is the inner `find` for the email.

You can go little further and make the function accept a field to match on as well like this:

```js
var obj = { "nextAction": [{ "userList": [{ "id": 8, "email": "testemail@gmail.com", "name": "John Doe" }], "buttonLabel": "Finalize Now" }] }

const getUser = (field="email", usr) => obj.nextAction.some(({userList}) => 
  userList ? userList.find(y => y[field] === usr): false)

console.log(getUser("email", "testemail@gmail.com"))    // true
console.log(getUser("name", "John Doe"))                // true
```

Comment: Will this work with userList being a null condition?

Comment: Wait but I though your 2nd rule was: `The userList array shouldn't contain the null element.`?

Comment: Yes I also need to verify that the userList doesn't have any null entry

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Array.reduce()` for this:

```js
const data = [{ "userList": [{ "id": 8, "email": "testemail@gmail.com", "name": "John Doe" }], "buttonLabel": "Finalize Now" }];

function checkForMyNextActions(myNextActions, currentUser) {
  const checkUsername = obj => obj.email === currentUser;
  return myNextActions.reduce((a,curr)=>{
    let bool = curr.userList.length && curr.userList.every(userList =>userList !==null) &&  curr.userList.some(checkUsername);
    return bool && a;
  },true) != 0;
  
}

var result = checkForMyNextActions(data, "testemail@gmail.com")
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkForMyNextActions` returns undefined because `forEach` returns undefined. Use `map` to call a function on each element in an array and return a new array with the return values of the functions. Also the inner function passed to `forEach` does not return anything.